Deceleration exerted by air against object tipping over
How is the deceleration exerted by air against an object that is tipping over to one of its sides calculated?
The object tipping over is a rectangular rigid mirror that is 1.63 m tall, 0.43 m wide and weighs 5.5 kg, evenly distributed.
It falls from a vertical position, supported on one of its short sides. Starting at a velocity that approaches 0 and the only force that tips it over is gravity.
The air density is 1.2 kg/m^3. There is no turbulence.
I want to calculate the deceleration from the start of the fall to the point at which the mirror is at an angle of 0.31 radians with respect to the floor.

This might take more than a few paragraphs. The place to start might be this video on DRAG ON FLAT PLATE. It talks about the force that air exerts on a flat plate as it flows. This gives rise to a boundary layer, where air is stopped right against the plate. Far from the plate, it flows uninterrupted. There is a transition from stopped to flowing as distance from the plate increases. So the answer isn't simple, but it is reasonably straightforward.
The flow over a mirror at an angle is similar to the video. But you would have to watch more videos to find out how to handle it.
If you are interested in the acceleration of the air, you need to look at the path of an air element as it flows into the boundary layer.
